# Powershell Workflow: Using if/else statement?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a workflow in order to make a script run faster by running a ping on several machines in parallel.  Where I am getting stuck is trying to use my if/else statement within the workflow and adding log entries based on the results of the ping.  Right now, it is not writing anything to the logs based on the ping results.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am open to suggestions for different methods to do this, as long as they do not involve using a module.  I want to stick with just Powershell code (I do not have permissions to install modules on the server where this would be running).  Thank you!  Here is my current code:

```
<#  
.NOTES
===========================================================================
 Created on:    10/6/2016 8:06 AM
 Created by:    
 Organization:  
 Filename:      Get-MPOSOfflinePrinters.ps1
===========================================================================
.DESCRIPTION
#> 

$logfile = "D:\Logs\MPOSPrinterPingLog.txt"
$offlineprinters = "D:\Reports\MPOS\MPOSOfflinePrinters.txt"
If (Test-Path $logfile) {Remove-Item $logfile}
If (Test-Path $offlineprinters) {Remove-Item $offlineprinters}

Add-Content $logfile "Setting local path"
$localPath = "C:\Temp\MPOS"

Add-Content $logfile "Gathering server list"
$serverList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'Q0*P30' -or Name -like 'Q0*P32'" -SearchBase "OU=Print,OU=Prod,OU=POS,DC=COMPANY,DC=NET").name | Sort-Object | Out-File C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSPrintServers.txt
$serverListPath = "C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSPrintServers.txt"

#Retrieve a list of MPOS Print servers from text file and set to $serverNames
Add-Content $logfile "Compiling text file"
$serverNames = Get-Content -Path $serverListPath

#Iterate through each of the server names
foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {

Add-Content $logfile "Processing $serverName" 

    #Check if the server is online before doing the remote command
    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Quiet -count 1) {

        Add-Content $logfile "$serverName is online"

        #copy config file from MPOS print to local server for processing
        $timestamp1 = (Get-Date -Format g)
        Add-Content $logfile "$timestamp1 - Copying xml file from server to local path"
        $configPath = "\\$($serverName)\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Point Of Service\Configuration\Configuration.xml"
        Copy-Item $configPath $localPath 

        #process xml file to parse IP addresses for ping
        $timestamp2 = (Get-Date -Format g)
        Add-Content $logfile "$timestamp2 - Processing xml file from $serverName to parse data to csv"
        $xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\Temp\MPOS\Configuration.xml)
        $PrinterNames = $xml.selectNodes('//PointOfServiceConfig/ServiceObject/Device') | foreach {New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{LogicalName=$_.LogicalName.Name}}
        $PrinterIPs = $xml.selectNodes('//PointOfServiceConfig/ServiceObject/Device') | foreach {New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{HardwarePath=$_.HardwarePath}} 

        workflow Test-WFConnection {

            param(

            [string[]]$PrinterIPs

            )

            foreach -parallel ($PrinterIP in $PrinterIPs) {

                $pingableIP = $PrinterIP.HardwarePath

                If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $pingableIP -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

                    $timestamp3 = (Get-Date -Format g)
                    Add-Content -Path $logfile -Value ("$timestamp3 - $serverName, $pingableIP is online and pingable")

                } #If (Test-Connection $pingableIP -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

                Else {

                $timestamp3 = (Get-Date -Format g)
                Add-Content -Path $offlineprinters -Value ("$timestamp3 - $serverName, $pingableIP is offline!")

                } #Else

           } #foreach -parallel ($PrinterIP in $PrinterIPs) {

        } #workflow Test-WFConnection {

        Test-WFConnection -PSComputerName $PrinterIPs

    } #If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Quiet -count 1) {

    Else {

        Add-Content $logfile "$serverName is offline!"

    } #Else

} #foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {
```

Comment: "I am trying to use a workflow in order to make a script run faster by running a ping on several machines in parallel." - don't do that - Workflows are not designed for speed, but resiliency. Use [runspaces](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Invoke-Ping/) or jobs for this instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - I was able to open your link to runspaces, thank you for the information.  However, this is about 900+ lines of code - what exactly should I be looking at here?  My current script is less than 100 lines of code.  I am not sure how to incorporate your suggestion.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm trying to convince you to not re-invent the wheel :) (and also *not* use workflows for performance reasons)

Comment: Understood - but I am not sure where to go with your suggestion.  Looking through all of that code...I have no idea why I would need to do all of that.  It seems like this could be simpler.  I am open to the runspaces suggestion, but how do I incorporate that here, without having to reinvent what I have already written?  :)  I do appreciate your quick responses and assistance - very much so.

Comment: Are the PowerShell cmdlets that you are using in your Workflow function available in the Windows Workflow Foundation? If they aren't, they may be getting called in a separate/new PowerShell window as WWF doesn't know what to do with them. They will be called as an inlinescript. Your variables won't be available to it then. That might be why you aren't getting any output. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: @TimHaintz - that actually makes a lot of sense.  Thank you.

Comment: No worries @Lilith. Hope it helps. Nicely formatted code too. :)